Rational model for composition of linear isometries
There is a composition map on spaces of linear isometries (over $\mathbb{C}$ say)
$$
\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{C}^k, \mathbb{C}^\ell) \times \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{C}^\ell, \mathbb{C}^m) \longrightarrow \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{C}^k, \mathbb{C}^m)
$$
which is a continuous map of topological spaces, where one may identify the space of linear isometries $\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{C}^k, \mathbb{C}^\ell)$ with the Stiefel manifold of $k$-frames in $\mathbb{C}^\ell$.
The spaces of linear isometries have rational models, given by their (co)homology. In particular, a rational model for the space of linear isometries $\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{C}^k, \mathbb{C}^\ell)$ is the exterior algebra (over $\mathbb{Q}$)
$$
\Lambda(x_{2(\ell-k)+1}, \dots, x_{2\ell-1}).
$$
on generators $x_i$ in degree $i$. This is explained for instance in Example 2.40 of the book "Algebraic Models in Geometry" by Félix, Oprea and Tarné.

Is there a map (of chain complexes) $$ \Lambda(x_{2(\ell-k)+1}, \dots, x_{2\ell-1}) \otimes \Lambda(x_{2(m-\ell)+1}, \dots, x_{2m-1}) \longrightarrow \Lambda(x_{2(m-k)+1}, \dots, x_{2m-1})$$ which corresponds geometrically to the composition map on spaces of linear isometries?

Here the term "geometrically" is up for debate: the naive hope is that the generators in these exterior algebras are (looped) Chern classes and the composition map is represented by an interaction between these Chern classes.
